# how to validate a form using phpunit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In below code a feedback form takes input for 3 fields like name, email id & comments. So validation needs to be tested using phpunit test. please help on this. I am new to php syntax altogether. how to assert & check valdiation to give report in phunit testing.

```
  if($_POST){
     //echo $sRc;
     //print "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;
     require_once(CLASSPATH."/utility.class.php");
     $oUtility      = new utility();
     $sRc           = base64_decode($_COOKIE['Rc_cf']);
     $sEmail            = trim($_POST['emailid']);
     $scomment      = trim($_POST['comment']);
     $syour_name        = trim($_POST['your_name']);
     $sOthereSubject = trim($_POST['subject']);

     $sName         = trim(strip_tags($oUtility->nonxmlcharreplace($_REQUEST['your_name'])));
     $sEmail            = trim(strip_tags($oUtility->nonxmlcharreplace($_REQUEST['emailid'])));
     $sComments     = trim(strip_tags($oUtility->nonxmlcharreplace($_REQUEST['comment'])));

     $iError=0;
     $sErrorMsg="";

     if(strlen($sName)==0){
        $sErrorMsg="Your name cannot be blank.";
        $iError=1;
    }     else if(strlen($sEmail)==0){
        $sErrorMsg="Email address cannot be blank.";
        $iError=1;
    }else if(strlen($sEmail)>0){

        $iValid = $oUtility->isValidEmail($sEmail);
        if($iValid!=1){
             $sErrorMsg="Please enter valid email address.";    
             $iError=1;
         }      
      }
      if(empty($sComments) && strlen($sErrorMsg)==0){
         $sErrorMsg="Comment cannot be blank.";
         $iError=1;
     }

     if(strlen($sErrorMsg)==0){
         require_once(CLASSPATH."feedback.class.php");      
         $oFeedback     = new feedback();

         if($iError==0){
            $aParameters=Array('name'=>$sName,'email'=>$sEmail,'comments'=>$sComments,'cdate'=>'now()',     'is_active'=>1,'cdate'=>'now()','udate'=>'now()');
            $iRes = $oFeedback->addUpdFeedback($aParameters);
            $sInserMsg = 1;
            $sEmail = $sName = $scomment='';

         }

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be hard to test because it's too long. To build your test you have to follow three steps :

1. Setup the context (here, define some input data)
2. Execute the function (here, a big function with a if statement in the middle)
3. Assert that the expected behavior happens (here, the validation fail or pass and other things happen in your big function)

The goal of **unit** testing is to test small things, **unit** things. So in your case it's very hard to write your test because it's hard to define a different input `$_POST` in a test context. It's also hard because your function do a lot of different things.

So you have to cut your big function into smaller ones and just test this functions one by one.

For example, something like that :

```
$errorsArray = $this->validation($_POST);
if (count($errorsArray) == 0) {
     require_once(CLASSPATH."feedback.class.php");      
     $oFeedback     = new feedback();
     $aParameters=Array('name'=>$sName,'email'=>$sEmail,'comments'=>$sComments,'cdate'=>'now()',     'is_active'=>1,'cdate'=>'now()','udate'=>'now()');
     $iRes = $oFeedback->addUpdFeedback($aParameters);
     $sInserMsg = 1;
     $sEmail = $sName = $
}
```

//

```
public static function validation($input)
{
    //Your validation here, return an array of error messages
}
```

Then, you will just have to write somme test cases like this ones :

```
public function testValidationOk()
{
    $input = array('name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com');
    $errorsArray = MyClass::validation($input);
    assertCount(0, $errorsArray);
}

public function testValidationFailWithoutName()
{
    $input = array('name' => '', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com');
    $errorsArray = MyClass::validation($input);
    assertCount(1, $errorsArray);
}

public function testValidationFailWithInvalidEmail()
{
    $input = array('name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john.com');
    $errorsArray = MyClass::validation($input);
    assertCount(1, $errorsArray);
}
```

The rest of your function will be tested in other tests cases. Small methods is the key of testability, readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks will try out with above suggestions.

Comment: Are you ok with the test of your code ? If you don't need more explanation about that, don't forget to close your question :)